# How to get to the date of the uploaded file

Tags: filters, uploads, date, limit

Anyone can tell which is the filter (if there is any) used for the date of an uploaded file. This can be useful to limit the upload for the users based on the time.

Comment: Media Library attachments create an entry in the posts table of the database just like any post or page. You should be able to query the database for the date field with standard mysql.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to filter the attachments shown in the media library, so that only attachments within a certain time period are shown? Keep in mind that WordPress doesn't deal with files directly, it deals with posts of type `attachment`, which represent those files.

Comment: `$file_date = get_the_date( $file_id )` should do the work?